# How many connections Meteor creates to mongodb?

Tags: meteor, compose-db

I have a meteor app with one nodejs process. It connects to compose with oplog.

There's only me on the server but I see that there's 27 connections in the compose stats.

Looking at the server, "netstat -ap" shows that node really have 27 connections.

I don't find any info aboute the heuristic Meteor made to creates a mongodb connection.